# How to allow page zoom on iPad but not iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, zooming, viewport

I'm building a website that responds to `iPhones`. To get the screen to scale to the screen scale I'm using the meta tag:

```
meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; 
maximum-scale=1.0;"
```

The downside is that this tag also prevents iPads from zooming in and out, is there a way I can allow zooming on iPads but not on iPhones?

Comment: What is your server-side language?

Answer (score 3):

I agree that you are better to do it with server-side 
in PHP

```
<?php
    // we only give the viewport if it is not an iPad:
    if(!(bool) stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'ipad')) { ?>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
<?php } ?>
```

But you can also do it with Javascript if you feel the need (but again, not sure why? as it is not as reliable! )

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null) { } else {
document.write('[meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;  " /]');  
}
```

replace the [ with a <  ...as I am not sure why the tags are being escaped in StackOveflow editor.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you use some kind of server-side language (PHP, ASP, and so on) to detect what the browsers user agent is? The iPhone and iPad has two different user agent strings. Only when you detect that the user agent is an iPhone, you set the meta tag.

A typical user agent string can be found by googling "iphone user agent string" and "ipad user agent string".

Comment: That's a possibility, but hoping to find a solution that will work for any device that can read the meta tags

Comment: Not sure I see what your problem is with this solution. If you're doing the user-agent detection server-side, it WILL work for any device.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is the same page you are referring to, you cannot really control the zooming behavior from front end side only..

You can use 2 separate JSPs which would have the relevant meta tags coded and then include them dynamically based on where the request is coming from through user agent string..

Again you wuld surely have to use some kind of server side technology to achieve what uou want...

Comment: Separate pages not ideal really. No reason some if / else logic can't be applied in his template.